# Adding properties for a Polymer element to observe based on content or a better way to handle forms

Tags: polymer

I need to create a form using the Polymer Paper-Input elements, and I need a way to know when all required content has been filled out.

I looked for a built in element, but didn't see one.  So I wanted to create a polymer form element that would wrap all of the input tags.  The resulting element would have an Invalid attribute which lets you know if any of the input tags are invalid.

The use of the tag would look like this:

```
<test-form id="testform">
    <paper-input label="test" required error="This field is required"></paper-input>
</test-form>

Invalid: {{ $.testform.invalid }}
```

However, it appears that by the time in the elements lifecycle that I can loop over all the elements inside of the content tag, that anything added to the observe object is ignored.

Here is the code I was working on below:

```
<polymer-element name="test-form" attributes="invalid">
<template>
    <content id="content">
    </content>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer('test-form', {
        domReady: function () {
            this.observe = {};

            for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
                this.observe["this.children[" + i + "].invalid"] = "valChanged";
            }
        },
        invalid: false,
        valChanged: function (oldValue, newValue) {
            // TODO: If newValue is true set invalid to true
            //       If newValue is false, loop over all elements to see if all are now valid and invalid can be set to false.
            alert("VALUE CHANGED" + oldValue + newValue);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Is there a better way to handle this or does anyone know how to make changes to what polymer is observing at this point in the lifecycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as checking the form's validity, you could simply check each form element's `invalid` property:

```
validate: function() {
  var invalid = false;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.children, function(child) {
    if (child.invalid === true) {
      invalid = true;
    }
  });
  this.invalid = invalid;
}
```

Then you could add an `input` event listener and run this method each time a form element's input changes.

Here's a [working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gunumatu/1/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, your high level goal is form validation?

As has been detailed in polycasts and other places, I have used iron-form which has some very powerful validate() functionality, including what you mention above and much more.

It does sometimes require some odd usages of hidden `<input>` fields to get all of the work done, but this is easy to learn in the polycasts, such as polycast 55 and 56

If you stumbled upon this question in 2017, you would definitely now want to use more primitive tech, after you've seen what this has to offer.